# Linux: How to count the number of symbols in a line, print the number, then the line?

Tags: linux

I have a file full of paths like this:

> parent_dir/chid_dir1/child_dir2
>
> parent_dir/chid_dir1/child_dir2/child_dir3

Is there a utility I can use that will count the number of "/" per line, print that number and print the line next to it?

I would like output like this:

> 2     parent_dir/chid_dir1/child_dir2
>
> 3     parent_dir/chid_dir1/child_dir2/child_dir3

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `awk` like this

```
awk -F/ '{print NF-1,$0}' file_full_of_paths
```

Comment: It is not needed the redirector operator `<`. `awk` can read directly the file `awk -F/ '{print NF-1,$0}'  file_full_of_paths`

Comment: @Hastur, uh, oops, yes of course. Thank you. I was thinking "UUOC" rather than about `awk` itself. I'll edit and fix.